# Contents within a .bat file not running properly when running said .bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, utf

So I've encountered a very odd problem while trying to run this java application I've just compiled. I wrote this very simple .bat file to run the program with just one parameter:

```
@echo off
java –Dproperties.location=%~dp0config.properties -jar userspro-ak.jar >> logs.log
pause
```

but when I run it, this happens:
[I'm really confused as to why instead of writing -D it writes those weird characters I'm not familiar with, but because of that, the program won't run!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5tkm.png)

Already ran the command in CMD writing it by hand and the application booted succesfully.
Please help, does anyone please know what I can do to fix this? Is it my Windows install or something?

Comment: Make sure the .BAT file was saved as an ANSI text file and not UTF-8

Comment: You should probably make sure that you are using a standard dash _(hyphen)_ character, not an en-dash. You can clearly see that the other twodash  characters in the code you've posted do not look the same as it, so copy one of those and paste it  over that en-dash as a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6th character in your batch file looks like a dash. **But it is not a dash**. It is an em-dash, or some other dash-like character from the higher unicode plane.

Go in, fix it. Replace it with an actual dash. Open it with an editor, highlight the dash, and hit the - key on your keyboard. For good measure, do this to all the dash-like constructs in there.

Comment: To be exact it is UTF-8 E2 80 93 for Unicode U+2013 EN DASH (which is in a higher _block_ but the same _plane_, BMP)